# How do I create a single JSON object with multiple attributes/properties?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to create a single JSON object called args with 2 attributes/property, key1 and key2.

Currently this is what I have but it is not being parsed correctly...

```
var args:{
   'key1': $scope.args.users, 
   'key2': 'http://financialsystems.sungard.com/'
}
```

where $scope.args.users is an array:

```
$scope.args.users = [
        {id: '1', firstName: 'Geraldine', lastName: 'Roberts', email: 'geraldine.roberts@email.com', country: 'South Africa'},
        {id: '2', firstName: 'Walter', lastName: 'Mitty', email: 'w.mitty@email.com', country: 'USA'}
    ];
```

Where am I going wrong? Should there be another set of braces around each attribute/property?

Comment: Do you need to create an object or the json reprensentation of that object?

Comment: What does "is not being parsed correctly" mean? Error message? Wrong content?

Comment: @vc I need to create a json object

Comment: @Tone There is no such thing as "JSON object". What you have there is a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Juhana I need to access the object in an angularjs partial using this syntax - {{panelArgs.key2}} or {{panelArgs.key1}} and I can't do this with the current object structure.

Comment: json is just an object serialization mechanism that works well with js

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: In JSON an entity wrapped in curly braces (`{ }`) is referred to as an object. JSON is just an object notation format for string data that is friendly with/parseable in JavaScript, yes, but it's pedantic to the point of being _wrong_ to say that "there is no such thing as a JSON object". That's the name given to that entity type and it's how millions of developers refer to it, just like entities wrapped in `[]` are referred to as "JSON arrays". Anyone will know what you are talking about--ignore those saying such things as "there's no such thing as a JSON object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't start a JSON object with a label. It looks like you are missing `{}` around yours
2. Property names in JSON must be strings. `args` needs to be `"args"`
3. Strings must be quoted with `"` not `'`. `'key1'` needs to be `"key1"`, etc
4. You can't use variables in JSON at all

Such:

```
{
    "args": {
        "key1": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "firstName": "Geraldine",
                "lastName": "Roberts",
                "email": "geraldine.roberts@email.com",
                "country": "South Africa"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "firstName": "Walter",
                "lastName": "Mitty",
                "email": "w.mitty@email.com",
                "country": "USA"
            }
        ],
        "key2": "http://financialsystems.sungard.com/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `:` to `=`

```
 var args = {
   'key1': $scope.args.users, 
   'key2': 'http://financialsystems.sungard.com/'
  };
```